# Problem with speech dispatcher

Tags: sound, shutdown

I had some problems with shutdown/restarting Ubuntu 13.04. It used to hang in a black screen with some codes about speech dispatcher. I searched the web and found a solution:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

Inside the file I changed the RUN property to yes, so the file started looking like this:

```
# Defaults for the speech-dispatcher initscript, from speech-dispatcher

# Set to yes to start system wide Speech Dispatcher
RUN=yes
```

I did so, the problem was solved but it disabled my internal speaker and mic. It looks like I have to choose between proper shutdowns and working mic/speaker.

Is there any solution to have them both working?

Hardware: DELL Inspiron n5110

Distro: Ubuntu 13.04 64bit

Comment: solved by removing speech-dispatcher from start-up apps.

Comment: @AmirA The AskUbuntu way of acknowledging an answer is to vote it up and mark as accepted.  After which comments could be deleted. :)

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to uninstall/remove the speech-dispatcher to achieve a proper shutdown. Just remove it from automatic start/stop at the time of system boot/shutdown.

Use the command:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f speech-dispatcher remove
```

Answer (score 6):

Unless you need speech-dispatcher, you can just disable it. I installed Boot-up-manager:

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

..and then I disabled speech-dispatcher:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with rebooting and would get errors about speech dispatcher and using BUM and disabling it worked but I don't think my built in mic works. I'm on a HP tc4200 with ubuntu 12.04 and loving it.

Answer (score 0):

Open file `/etc/default/speech-dispatcher` on your favorite editor with `sudo`.

Example: `sudo nano /etc/default/speech-dispatcher`

Chage:

```
RUN=yes
```

To:

```
RUN=no
```

Restart and you are ready.