# Yesterday my system was working fine. but today my system is not getting shut down

Tags: shutdown

Yesterday my system was working fine. but today my system is not getting shut down. When i give shut down it is giving the error message that 'Speed dispatcher stopped' . I am not sure that because of this my system is getting hang when i try to shut down . Please any one can help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `speech dispatcher`?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but do you mean speech rather than speed dispatcher?

If if it is speech dispatcher, take a look at the following link, this might be of help

[Problems with speech dispatcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293244/problem-with-speech-dispatcher)

Comment: i have done the same still the problem is there...  when i give  restart it is hanging with the message braoadcast by Bharath@bharath. Chacking battery. system is goigng to halt.acpic disabled... not sure about the message .. the message is some thing like this.. pls resolve my issue and also i am not able to get wifi connection .i am connecting only through wired Lan. Not able to see the wifi option also... would be great help if this resolved....