# Command sudo halt don't run : speed dispatcher disabled edit /etc/default /speed dispatcher

Tags: power-management

when I do `sudo halt` the computer shutdown but a black screen appear: where it was written lots of lines whose line Speed

```
dispatcher  edit /etc/defaut/speed-dispatcher
```

Comment: `halt` is not supposed to bring the system down. Maybe what you want to do is actually `sudo poweroff`?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, according to the [reboot 8 man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/reboot.8.html), `halt` actually is supposed to bring down the system ;) I'll post a more detailed about speech-dispatcher in a minute.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: have you actually tried it?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, ah, I see what you mean. Learned something new today ;) I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updated as per comment above: Your computer is probably behaving as it should. There's a difference between "halt" and "poweroff" (and "reboot", of course).

**Reboot** means, as you probably know, "shutdown the operating system, then restart it".

**Halt** means, "shutdown the operating system, then leave the machine as it is, so the human operator can do as he pleases (reboot, power off or whatever he wants)".

**poweroff** means, "shutdown the operation system, then power off the machine".

There are commands for all three of those, called `reboot`, `halt` and `poweroff`. Additionally, you can use the `shutdown` command which offers options which way of shutdown you want, `shutdown -h now`, `shutdown -r now` etc. For more information, see `man shutdown`. Of course, there's a man page for `reboot`, `halt` and `poweroff` as well.

---

Maybe the line you're seeing is about *speech-dispatcher* rather than *speed-dispatcher*? There are applications for Ubuntu that allow you to synthesize speech, for example to have the computer read texts for visually impaired users. [speech-dispatcher](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/speech-dispatcher) is a package that supplies a common interface that such speech synthesizers can use. It looks like you installed that package (maybe as a dependency for some other package), but didn't configure it. If want to use speech-dispatcher, you'd probably want to configure it. If you don't, you can disable it to be started at boot time. This can for example be done with the graphic run level editor `bum`, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/294999/48867).

This should get rid of the "speech-dispatcher" line, but not necessarily of all lines. Ubuntu writes a lot of information to its terminal, about what it's doing, maybe what went wrong and such. When you start the graphical interface, it "covers" those messages. When you stop the graphical interface, the messages get visible again. So it's possible that the messages you're seeing are not from the boot process, not from the shutdown process.

In my estimation, your problem mostly is that when you command your computer to shutdown, it shuts down the graphical interface, but for some reason can't shut down the computer as a whole. Maybe your machine doesn't support it, or maybe something can't be terminated properly. Judging from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293244/problem-with-speech-dispatcher), speech-dispatcher *may* be the cause, but this is mostly guesswork. If you disabled speech-dispatcher and your machine still doesn't shutdown properly, I'd look into the [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acpi) support of your machine.

Comment: I will try the command poweroff,

Comment: Poweroff run ! 
Thanks you henning Kockerbeck, halt just takes on a black screen