# Ubuntu 14.04 on Toshiba suddenly super slow

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, performance, restart

I have a Toshiba Satellite C55 with Ubuntu 14.04 with a 320GD HDD and 6GB RAM. It dual boots with Windows 8 (which I never log into). I usually completely shut-down the laptop only every 2 days.

Since the last time I did it has become very slow. I have no idea. It won't shut-down, gets stuck on the Ubuntu splash logo (it gets stuck at `speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher`). I have to Power it down. When I turn it back on, it takes about 5 minutes to reach the login screen. After I login, all the apps show up after a few minutes. It takes about ~3min to launch the browser. Wifi has become slow, suddenly.

Any suggestions? I have no idea what is going on!

Comment: Have you ever installed a driver with the "intel driver update utility"?

Comment: No, never! Should I?

Comment: no, just that there were problems with the latest update on it, so ruling that out

Comment: Do you have intel or amd?

Comment: I have Intel..!

Comment: @Mateo what problems were there? I wasn't aware. It's been working fine for me so far.

Comment: check this out http://askubuntu.com/questions/293244/problem-with-speech-dispatcher

Comment: must be related to a certain chipset, but I have read about and experienced problems such as the comments on: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/intel-graphics-installer-linux-updated-1-0-6

Comment: please consider asking two separate questions: one for the boot up problem and one for the slow system